# Is my route group intended for routes that require admin role written correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to remove the admin middleware from specific routes and create a Route::group for admin routes only but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

I'm trying to turn this:

```
Route::get('/admin', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@admin',
    'as' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => 'Admin'
]);
```

Into this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => ['admin']], function(){
    Route::get('/admin', 'pagesController@admin')->name('admin');
});
```

So this route group is meant to only pass people who have the role of admin to the routes. I believe it is working but I really wanna check if I have made the change correctly.

Middleware:

```
class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() === null){
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        $actions = $request->route()->getAction();
        $roles = isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
        if ($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles ) {
                return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Roles aren't a part of Laravel, you may want to add if you're using a package or a specific middleware.

Comment: I've created a middleware for my roles, they're working as intended. Up until now I've used the first way of setting the used middleware but it becomes ugly when I have to apply it to many routes, so I'm trying to make a route group that uses the middleware. I am just not sure if this is the right way to apply the middleware to my Route::group and pass the required role ( I have more than 1 roles )

Comment: Well, the differences are you have a capital 'A' on admin and you use an array in the latter example.  Without seeing your middleware or how it works, can't really say what will work.

Comment: I've added my middleware.

Comment: I dont see any reason for it to not work. Do you intend to put more routes into this route group?

Comment: Yes I'll put a couple more routes in the group. I'm not saying it shouldn't be working, I'm just asking if I have made the transition right.